# Notice: Undefined index in vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 2735 (Symfony 2.1)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have got two entities associated with OneToOne association.
This is how it all looks like:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @ORM\Table(name="a")
 */
class A
{
....

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="B", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
     */
    private $b;
}
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="b")
 */
class B
{
....
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $aId;        
}
```

What I am trying to do is to crate lifeCycleCallback preUpdate on A class. 
While calling preUpdate A class already has its on ID. I have tried to do something like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function update()
{
    if (is_null($this->getB()))
        $this->b = new B();
    $this->b->setAId($this->id)->setType('A'/* classname */);
}
```

B class has to store classname in type filed and object id in aId field. I cannot use foreign keys here.

The problem is that the above update function returns this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: 000000006914b7950000000033b7b784 in C:...\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 2735

Any ideas what this error means and how to solve it?

**EDIT**
This is how I fetch A object before passing it to edit form:

```
$this->getEntityManager()
                    ->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('a,b')
                    ->from('MyBundle:A', 'a')
                    ->leftJoin('a.b','b')
                    ->where('a.id = :aId')
                    ->setParameter('aId', $id)
                    ->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

I do edit only A object (in form) and want to create associated B object on first A update and make some changes to this B object on every next update of A.

**EDIT2**
The above error no longer displays. However changes made to B object in `@ORM\PreUpdate` of A object are never persisted even when association to be has `cascade={"all"}`.
Here is the example:

```
/**
 * inside A class !
 *
 * @ORM\PreUpdate
 */
public function update()
{
    $this->lastModified = new \DateTime();        
    $this->getB()
            ->setSomething('something'); // <-- this is never stored to db by cascade 
}
```

Comment: Have did you retrieve the `A` object? Did you use JOIN fetch? Because you haven't specified `FetchType` to be `EAGER` the `$this->b` is **never** `null` but instead it holds the proxy object.

Comment: Ok, that is the way it should be retrieved. The error you've encountered could indeed be bug in Doctrine - have you tried updating it?

Comment: @jperovic I have changed some thing in my A class and 'undefined index error' no longer exists. But changes made to B object in `PreUpdate` of A object are not persisted to database. Could you please take a look at my EDIT2 above.

Comment: I guess I should probably ask a new question because it no longer applies to this topic.

Comment: There must be something with the `preUpdate` function. When I change something in B class before `preUpdate` is called changes are saved for both A and B class.